# External interrupt does not work on Proteus (PIC16F883)

Tags: microcontroller, pic, interrupts, proteus, hi-tech-compiler

I'm developing a basic circuit for a shooting game. When some area of the target is reached the microcontroller must add the current value to the reached value.

My problem is that I can not make any interrupts work on Proteus. 
(RB0 external interrupt)

I'm using the Hi-tech C compiler (free version)

What am I doing wrong?

```
/* Main.c file generated by New Project wizard
*
* Created:   qua jul 12 2017
* Processor: PIC16F883
* Compiler:  HI-TECH C for PIC10/12/16
*/

#include <htc.h>



//digits (0-9)
const unsigned char disp[] = {0b00111111,0b00000110,0b01011011,0b01001111,0b01100110,0b01101101,0b01111101,0b00000111,0b01111111,0b01101111 };

//enable specific display using array index
const unsigned char ob[] = {0b00010000,0b00000010,0b00000100,0b00001000};

void set_display(int val, int display);

int value = 0; 
int total = 0;

void interrupt rb0(void){

   if(INTF){
      value = RA0 + (RA1 * 2) + (RA2 * 3) + (RA3 * 4) + (RA4 * 5) + (RA6 * 6);

      total += value;

      INTF = 0;
   }   
}

void main(void)
{

   // Set RB0 as input
   // Set RB1 - RB7 as output
   TRISB = 0b00000001;
   PORTB = 0xff;

   // Set RC as output (default 0)
   TRISC=0X00;
   PORTC=0X00;

   TRISB0 = 1;
   GIE = 1;
   PEIE = 1;
   INTEDG = 1;
   INTE = 1;   

   //Set internal oscilator to 8MHz
   IRCF2 = 1;
   IRCF1 = 1;
   IRCF0 = 1;

   while (1){
      int a = total/100;
      int b = (total/10)%10;
      int c = total%10;

      set_display(value,0);
      __delay_ms(25);

      set_display(a,1);
      __delay_ms(25);

      set_display(b,2);
      __delay_ms(25);

      set_display(c,3);
      __delay_ms(25);

   }

 }



 void set_display(int val, int display){
    PORTC = disp[val];
    PORTB = ob[display];    
 }
```

[image: Target Project]

Download project(Proteus 8.5) and compiler: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AipcmZDTZPIPlOknaPJ06hKTQbzLiA

Comment: "*External interrupt does not work on Proteus (PIC16F883)*"  It is more likely that you cannot get external interrupt to work on Proteus, not that external interrupt doesn't work on Proteus. More accurately characterizing your problem can help find its root cause sooner for you.

Comment: I thought I would add some code pieces to help you but somehow my post was deleted so i have no place to post the code. best of luck in tracking down your issues.

Comment: @dannyf I added a link to download the project and compiler. The folder is public and you can upload any sample file into it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (I do assembler, I don't like the curly braces languages) but I can't see you setting the Interrupt On Change registers for the port (IOCBP or IOCBN) anywhere in your code.

Comment: @IanBland Looking at the datasheet, the PIC16F883 does not have the registers IOCBP and IOCBN. To enable the interrupt I am using: GIE (Global Interrupt bit), INTEDG (Interrupt on rising edge bit), PEIE (Peripheral Interrupt Enable bit), INTE (INT External Interrupt Enable bit)

Comment: Ah yes, it appears to be register IOCB (3-8 in the datasheet) that enables interrupt on change on the pins. I was thinking in terms of the 16F1776 I'm working on at the moment :) So for an IOC on PortB bit 0, you want to set bit 0 of IOCB, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On power up RB0 is set to analog mode, and all digital input on the pin is disabled. To enable digital I/O on RB0-5 you have to clear the appropriate bits in `ANSELH`.

`ANSELH = 0;` will make PORTB inputs digital.

Since you are using RA0-6 as digital inputs you should also clear `ANSEL`.

[image]